# idiomatic way to represent key-value maps in Redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, immutability, immer.js

I think that most examples I've seen online, when needing to maintain a key-value map in Redux store, they seem to choose to type it as an array of key-value pairs, e.g.:

```
employees: [{id: 42, emp: {name: 'John Doe'}}, {id: 43, emp: {name: 'Mary Loo'}}]
```

... typed as:

```
employees: Array<{id: number, emp: {name: string}}>
```

However, I would think instead that the following is a tighter typing as it explicitly disallows duplicate `id`:

```
employees: Record<id, {name: string}>
```

Is there a reason for choosing the former over the latter? I understand that Redux does a shallow comparison but I think that when using immutability libraries both array and object structs are equally well supported.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [the tutorial chapter on normalization](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd say that "the usual way is to keep it as an array".  A normalized lookup table of `Record<SomeId, SomeItem>` would definitely be the right answer here - a plain JS object where the keys are item IDs and the values are the items themselves.